# DOCmd can't find string containing SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Have the following code:

```
Dim SKbyYrByMo As String
SKbyYrByMo = "TRANSFORM Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS SumOfExtension" & _
" SELECT [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku, Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS [Total Of Extension]" & _
" FROM 1ACTMasterQuery" & _
" GROUP BY [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku" & _
" PIVOT [1ACTMasterQuery].MonthNo"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"SKbyYrByMo", _
"C:\Users\John\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx", _
True
```

If I change the name of the query to one in the ACCESS query list it works fine.
But when I use SKbyYrByMo I get the message

> 'The Microsoft database engine could not find the object 'SKbyYrByMo'.

Comment: Sorry about not indenting

Comment: Why are you not saving the VBA string query to an actual MS Access query? There is no value you are using from VBA. Do note: Access engine saves the best execution plan with stored queries. VBA queries run on the fly and so it is not optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a query/view and then point the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` to that newly created object as the "table" parameter:

```
SKbyYrByMo = "TRANSFORM Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS SumOfExtension" & _
" SELECT [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku, Sum([1ACTMasterQuery].Extension) AS [Total Of Extension]" & _
" FROM 1ACTMasterQuery" & _
" GROUP BY [1ACTMasterQuery].Year, [1ACTMasterQuery].Sku" & _
" PIVOT [1ACTMasterQuery].MonthNo"

'Create the view/query
CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef "SKbyYrByMo", SKbyYrByMo

'Now you can reference that:
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
acExport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
"SKbyYrByMo", _
"C:\Users\John\Desktop\RSExcel.xlsx", _
True

'And Delete the query:
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "SKbyYrByMo"
```

The reason for this is that the third parameter in the `TransferSpreadsheet` method [takes a string that is a "TableName"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb214141(v%3doffice.12)):

> A string expression that's the name of the Microsoft Access table you
>   want to import text data to, export text data from, or link text data
>   to, or the Microsoft Access query whose results you want to export to
>   a text file.

If you don't create the query then all you have is SQL in a variable that is a string (Not a tablename). So we create the querydef and then pass the name of that querydef into `TransferSpreadsheet` method, then blow away the querydef since we don't really need that object hanging out in the database.

It would be nice if, instead, that method took a sql string...

Comment: I ran your code and got to the db.CreateQueryDef "SKbyYrByMo", SKbyYrByMo and it bombed with Run-time error 424  Object required.  Don't quite understand your explanation, but will read up on it. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Change that `db.CreateQueryDef` to `CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef`

Comment: Thank you so much. It ran perfectly. I especially appreciate the time you took to produce your explanation. Now I must read so that I understand what makes it work.  jpl458-Chicago